# Bind a record from dataset or datatable to a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, label

Guys i want to print two records returned from a database to a label. I use dataset , browse through the column however could't bind as label does not have a datasource. Below is my code.

```
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);



    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lblClient.Enabled = true;
        lblClient.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Columns[0]);
        lblBranch.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Columns["Bname"]);


    }
    connection.Close();
```

when i tried the above. It returns only the column name (i.e the string specified). Any alternative would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want the column's text but the `DataRow` values:

```
lblClient.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>(0);
lblBranch.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>(1);
```

or by column-name (presumed the name of the first):

```
lblClient.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("Cname");
lblBranch.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("Bname");
```

This works only if the table contains at least one row. So you have to check that.

Answer (score 1):

you need to indicate the row has you want. With your code you select a column of DataTable

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    lblClient.Enabled = true;
    lblClient.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].[0]);
    lblBranch.Text = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].["Bname"]);


}
connection.Close();
```